# Use Zipped Static Resource for "Display Image" component in Lightning Flow?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, static-resources

In Lightning Flow, can I use Zipped Static Resource for "Display Image" component?
I'm building a Flow in the Lightning Flow Builder and I want to add images to the Flow. I already have a zipped static resource full of images, but it seems like the Lightning Flow only allows me to select static resource that has one image inside. Is there a way to reference subfolders with images inside a zipped static resource?
[image: Can I use zipped static resource from Lightning Flow?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I created an Aura Component that accepts a string variable for a zipped static resource as well as the path to the image inside the zip. The component then compiles the URL inside the controller and displays the image. This doesn't directly answer my question but solved my issue.

Comment: That seems to be the only workaround possible even after more than a year :-)